# Injector moduleerr in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am currently defining my ui-router states inside the module.run() using a custom provider. But when I define them inside module.config() I get an injector moduleerr error. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

For example

```
angular.module(module_name).run(function(custom_provider))
```

works fine but

```
angular.module(module_name).config(function(custom_provider))
```

gives the injector moduleerr error

Comment: add some relevant code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inject something that works in run but does not in config that means you inject the service instance of the provider. So here is how it works :

```
myAngularModule.provider('myService');// declaration
myAngularModule.config(function(myServiceProvider))// note the 'Provider' added
myAngularModule.run(function(myService))
```

So if you declare a provider `custom_provider` in the `config`phase you have to inject it as `custom_providerProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

from the docs -

```
Once the configuration phase is over, interaction with providers is disallowed and the process of creating services starts
```

read - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Comment: True but not the problem of author, if he declare a config block even after a run block, the config block will get executed first. The problem is that you can only inject provider in config phase and in run/controller/service you inject service/factory/filter